# How to get command line parameters in specific format?

Tags: c#

For example, we have option "--date".

I use `System.CommandLine` library to get options from command line and it works with such format:
"--date 2023-02-06", but I want it to work with format kind of: "--date=2023-02-06". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure, just parse it like you would any other string.  If you can already get `date 2023-02-06` then you can surely parse `date=2023-02-06` by [splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) it over the equals sign.

Comment: The Parser class is then used to parse the command line arguments and extract the value of the "--date" option, which is stored in the date variable.

Comment: `--date 2023-02-06` and `--date=2023-02-06` are equivalent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/syntax#option-argument-delimiters

Comment: Docs (as linked by shingo) say that all of these are handled identically: `--date 2023-02-06`, `--date=2023-02-06` and `--date:2023-02-06`. Did you try it? What does your `Option<>` setup look like?

Comment: @Corey yeah, it works, I just was inattentive. Thx everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a beta Microsoft library you could use System.CommandLine.

From [Option-argument delimiters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/syntax#option-argument-delimiters):

> Option-argument delimiters
>
> System.CommandLine lets you use a space, '=', or ':' as the delimiter between an option name and its argument. For example, the following commands are equivalent:
>
> ```
> dotnet build -v quiet
> dotnet build -v=quiet
> dotnet build -v:quiet
> ```

For example (This is modified [Tutorial: Get started with System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/get-started-tutorial)):

```
// dotnet add package System.CommandLine --prerelease
using System.CommandLine;


internal class Program
{ 
    static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        var date = new Option<string?>(
            name: "--date",
            description: "TODO");


        var rootCommand = new RootCommand("TODO");
        rootCommand.AddOption(date);

        rootCommand.SetHandler((date) => 
            { 
                Run(date!); 
            },
            date);

        return await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);

    }

    static void Run(string date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date);
    }
}
```

Then we can:

```
PS C:\git\games\bin\Release\net6.0\win10-x64\publish> .\games.exe --date 2023-02-06
2023-02-06
PS C:\git\games\bin\Release\net6.0\win10-x64\publish> .\games.exe --date:2023-02-06
2023-02-06
PS C:\git\games\bin\Release\net6.0\win10-x64\publish> .\games.exe --date=2023-02-06
2023-02-06
```